# How to change the generated launch.json file?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

When attempting to debug a project for the first time, Visual Studio Code prompts to select a debugger and then generates a launch.json file.
How would one go about making changes to what is generated, so that not every newly generated launch.json file must be manually adapted?
For example, Cargo of the Rust language will create an instrumented executable at `./target/debug/[project name]`, but the generated launch.json will contain `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/<your program>"`.
Ideally I could instruct VS Code to generate an adapted launch.json every time it detects a Cargo.toml file.

I have attempted adding a Rust-specific launch configuration to my user settings, but VS Code still generates an unchanged launch.json file.

Answer (score 0):

New to Rust as well. This one works for me and seems to be generic.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Cargo build",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "build"
                ]
            },
            "args": []
        },
    ]
}
```